# Django form practices

Tags: html, django, forms

Can I simulate form like behaviour when a user clicks on a simple  link?

For example, can I have in views.py

```
def remove(request, entity_id):
   #remove the object with entity_id here
```

And in the HTML

```
<a href="profile/remove/{{ obj.entity_id }}">
```

And in the urls.py

```
(r'^app/profile/remove/(?P<entity_id>\d+)', 'app.views.remove')
```

Or do I have to use a proper HTML form like in the [tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/#intro-tutorial04)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GET/HEAD requests should not have any harmful side-effects (from [HTTP 1.1 spec, 9.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html): "In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval."), that's what POST/PUT/DELETE methods are for.

Other than that - Django won't forbid deleting a row from DB on GET request, if that's what you ask.

Comment: Seconded, **always** use `post` for deletion.

Comment: you could also use delete for delete.  http has several methods!  of course you cannot use a form to generate a delete request (That i know of)

Comment: There are other methods, but adoptance across browsers are few, far between and different. If you don't want headaches, I'd recommend using `post` and `get` exclusively for web pages.